# Accessing Dispatcher IScheduler in .NET Standard libraries

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive, .net-standard

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766812/cross-thread-exception-when-using-rx-throttle) describes how to ensure `IObservable<>.Throttle` runs on the UI thread by passing the UI scheduler to `Throttle`. However my Observables are defined in a shared library that is based on .NET Standard 1.5. Is there an equivalent of `DispatcherScheduler.Instance` in .NET Standard or should I inject the Scheduler from the consuming (WPF/UWP/etc) libraries?

Comment: Yes, you should use the dispatch scheduler for all WPF/UWP code.

Comment: @Enigmativity DispatcherScheduler.Instance cannot be found in a .NET Standard project. I just compared System.Reactive 4.0 (pre) in a WPF and a .NET standard project. WPF still knows the DispatcherScheduler.Instance, .NET standard does not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class DispatcherScheduler is not existing in the System.Reactive assembly for .NET Standard.

A possible workaround is to use the `SynchronizationContextScheduler` with the current `SynchronizationContext`. When you are on the UI thread when `ObserveOn()` is called, the handler of the observable will run on the UI thread.

When `ObserveOn()` ist not called on the UI thread, the whole thing does not work. To avoid this case, you can create something like an `AppContext` object, set it up while UI Initialization happens and make it distributable in your application. Save the `SynchronizationContext.Current` inside this `AppContext` and you can make an observer on UI thread from everywhere where you have the `AppContext`.

```
IObservable<EventArgs> myObservable = GetSomeObservableEvents();
var myScheduler = new SynchronizationContextScheduler(SynchronizationContext.Current);
myObservable.ObserveOn(myScheduler).Subscribe(ev =>
{
    // some code that should run on UI thread
});
```

I use it like this in a Xamarin.Forms 2.5.0 project, where I have an app project in .NET Standard 2.0 containing ViewModels, Views and so on.

This answer is valid (at least) under this conditions:

- .NET Standard project version is  2.0
- System.Reactive has version 4.0.0-preview00001

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Its been a while but from memory I followed a similar approach and passed the context to the observers.